# Can you remove the boilerplate from Flutter widget testing?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing some Flutter tests for my widget and there is a lot of code that seems unnecessary, but I don't know how to run the tests without it.

I need to test the state of a custom widget. I have an existing `GlobalKey` to do that; so, I need to test with `testWidgets` instead of `test`.

Here is what I tried first:

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(
  MyTextField(
    key: myFieldKey,
  ),
);
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
No Material widget found.
TextField widgets require a Material widget ancestor within the closest LookupBoundary.
In Material Design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In
Flutter's material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is
the Material widget that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many
material library widgets require that there be a Material widget in the tree above them.
To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget
that contains Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.
```

Then I added a `Scaffold`:

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(
  Scaffold(
    body: MyTextField(
      key: myFieldKey,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Which gave me this error:

```
No Directionality widget found.
Scaffold widgets require a Directionality widget ancestor.
...
Typically, the Directionality widget is introduced by the MaterialApp or WidgetsApp
widget at the top of your application widget tree...
```

So, I added a `MaterialApp`:

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(
  MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: MyTextField(
        key: myFieldKey,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

And this worked! The problem is I'm basically building a new app every time I test. I am writing dozens of tests which all need to be pumped like this; this results in a lot of extra code and seems inefficient. Is there a way that my first try could work? That seems the most simple and intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter needs all of that extra structure to be able to function. Your `GlobalKey` and custom widget rely on context to work; however, without the `MaterialApp` and `Scaffold`, there is no context.

One way to handle this more neatly is to extract the widget pumping into its own method. That would look something like this:

```dart
Future<void> pumpMyTextField(
  WidgetTester tester,
  GlobalKey key,
) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyTextField(
          key: key,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

This could be called in all of your tests like this:

```dart
await pumpMyTextField(tester, myFieldKey);
```

This would make all of your tests a lot cleaner since the "boilerplate" code is extracted out and only written once.